# creating inset in matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib, insets

I have created a plot in matplot lib and I wish to add an inset to that plot. The data I wish to plot is kept inside of a dictionary that I use in other figures. I'm finding this data inside a loop which I then run this loop again for the subplot. Here is the relevant segment:

```
leg = []     
colors=['red','blue']
count = 0                     
for key in Xpr: #Xpr holds my data
    #skipping over what I don't want to plot
    if not key[0] == '5': continue 
    if key[1] == '0': continue
    if key[1] == 'a': continue
    leg.append(key)
    x = Xpr[key]
    y = Ypr[key] #Ypr holds the Y axis and is created when Xpr is created
    plt.scatter(x,y,color=colors[count],marker='.')
    count += 1

plt.xlabel(r'$z/\mu$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\rho(z)$')
plt.legend(leg)
plt.xlim(0,10)
#Now I wish to create the inset
a=plt.axes([0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8])
count = 0
for key in Xpr:
    break
    if not key[0] == '5': continue
    if key[1] == '0': continue
    if key[1] == 'a': continue
    leg.append(key)
    x = Xpr[key]
    y = Ypr[key]
    a.plot(x,y,color=colors[count])
    count += 1
plt.savefig('ion density 5per Un.pdf',format='pdf')

plt.cla()
```

The strange thing is that when I tried to move the inset position, I still get the previous insets (those from the previous run of the code). I even tried to comment out the `a=axes([])` line without any apparent. I attach en example file. Why is it acting in that way? [image: A figure of the crooked output]

Comment: Are you running this code in some interactive environment?

Comment: I'm running this through Emacs. There where better results when I used it directly in terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is you should use `plt.clf()` which clears the figure, not the current axes. There is also a `break` in the inset loop which means none of that code will ever run.

When you start to do more complicated things than use a single axes, it is worth switching over to using the OO interface to `matplotlib`.  It may seem more complicated at first, but you no longer have to worry about the hidden state of `pyplot`.  Your code can be re-written as

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,.8,.8]) # main axes
colors=['red','blue']
for key  in Xpr: #Xpr holds my data
    #skipping over what I don't want to plot
    if not key[0] == '5': continue 
    if key[1] == '0': continue
    if key[1] == 'a': continue
    x = Xpr[key]
    y = Ypr[key] #Ypr holds the Y axis and is created when Xpr is created
    ax.scatter(x,y,color=colors[count],marker='.',label=key)
    count += 1

ax.set_xlabel(r'$z/\mu$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\rho(z)$')
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
leg = ax.legend()

#Now I wish to create the inset
ax_inset=fig.add_axes([0.7,0.7,0.3,0.3])
count =0
for key  in Xpr: #Xpr holds my data
    if not key[0] == '5': continue
    if key[1] == '0': continue
    if key[1] == 'a': continue
    x = Xpr[key]
    y = Ypr[key]
    ax_inset.plot(x,y,color=colors[count],label=key)
    count +=1

ax_inset.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was too lazy to do this when I started this "project" and now the file is too long for me to change it.